# Storing change history in the file using SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, comments

Is there a way to store the change history in the files when using SVN ? For example, if you use Microsoft VSS then by adding a tag at the bottom of the file once, everytime when you check the file and add checkin comments  , these comments append themselves at the bottom of the file as source code comments with details of the user , date and time. Are there any such tags which can be used with SVN ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in SVN - but it puzzles me why you would want to. With most SVN clients you have the option to view all change logs for a given file.

There is a similar question here (see link below) and a couple of possible options are listed - although no correct answer has been flagged.

[Subversion: Add revision data to code file on commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008843/subversion-add-revision-data-to-code-file-on-commit)

I hope this helps!

Nick.