# To add a file with a revision number on commit in SVN

Tags: svn

I've not sure if this could be implemented with Subversion, but is there a way to add a file with the revision number on commit?

- File name: revision.txt
- Would only have one line: revision number
- If exists, update with new revision number

UPDATE:

OK, I've added this option to my SVN configuration

```
[auto-props]
enable-auto-props = yes
*.php = svn:keywords=Id
```

Here is the file I'm checking in with SVN (command line)

```
<?php
/**
 * $Id$
 */
?>
$Id$
```

Looking in the repository I only see the code above and not the revision number.

Comment: Are you talking about `$id$` keyword substitution? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.props.special.keywords

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subversion: Add revision data to code file on commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008843/subversion-add-revision-data-to-code-file-on-commit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this would help:

http://www.startupcto.com/server-tech/subversion/setting-the-id-tag

Comment: so just add $Id$ to a file and check it in?, testing now

Comment: Check that article, it's on the client side.

Comment: Thanks, had to propset the file as well: find . \( -name "*.php" -o -name "*.js" \) -exec svn propset svn:keywords Id {} \;

Comment: -1 This isn't an answer. [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/172319) post on meta explains what I mean in more detail but summarising, "answers" should contains answers, not just a link to something which may or may not answer the question **and** may or may not exist in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**Preface**

If you want to have global revision number for repository, you get *wrong solution* and implement even this bad solution in *not optimal way*

**Face**

- Max revision ID for repository is always accessible inside Working Copy without additional tricks.

> ```
> $svn info .
>
> ...
>
> Revision: 9012
> Node Kind: directory
>
> ...
>
> Last Changed Rev: 5381
>
> ...
> ```

or

> $svnversion
>
> 9012

- Revision of file (which differ from repo-revision) can be obtained with pure $Revision$ keyword
- Revision of file is **local** property, unrelated to repository revisions, show only when **this file was changes last time**, you have to change file revisions.txt on **every** commit in your workflow
- I see no reasons for using 1. auto-props 2. for all php-files. If you want tohave svn:keyword in one file, you can add keyword to this file (revisions.txt) and `svn propset` for this and only this file
- svn:keyword will be expanded to it's value **inside working copy**, all repo-browsers will show [source-text without expansion](http://www.assembla.com/code/customlocations-greylink/subversion/nodes/trunk/SignalTV.ini?rev=1143) (you can checkout shown file and see all used keywords nicely expanded)
- After all, if you want to provide 1. revision number 2. of repository 3. for unversioned copy of your sources (because for versioned WC we already have it), you can think about some type of building system, which, except 'svn export', build needed file with requested data **inside exported source tree**. Which tools (and technique) to use is OS-dependent (and a question of available tools): SubWCRev on Windows (part of TSVN) works nice, port and equivalent in Tux-world also exist. In common - you have versioned template-file, which (as part of build-process) is converted to file with actual fresh data, when you prepare unversioned bundle. Such way I get from `svn.exe export ... z:\trunk$WCDATE=%Y%m%d$-r$WCREV$` pattern command to export into unique dir-name and the same WCDATE template in text-file replaced with human-readable and informative data, `$WCDATE=%Y%m%d$-r$WCREV$` was **20120122-r1143** at latest commit