# Include SVN revision number in source code

Tags: java, svn, version-control, netbeans

My requirement is simple. At the beginning of each file there should be a block comment like this:

```
/*
 * This file was last modified by {username} at {date} and has revision number {revisionnumber}
 */
```

I want to populate the `{username}`, `{date}` and `{revisionnumber}` with the appropriate content from `SVN`.

How can I achieve this with `NetBeans` and `Subversion`? I have searched a lot but I can't find exactly what I need.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subversion: Add revision data to code file on commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008843/subversion-add-revision-data-to-code-file-on-commit)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008843/subversion-add-revision-data-to-code-file-on-commit) question and got some useful information. It is not exactly duplicate because I am working with `NetBeans` but the idea is the same. This is my header:

```
/*
 * $LastChangedDate$
 * $LastChangedRevision$
 */
```

Then I go to **Team > Subversion > Svn properties** and add `svn:keywords` as property name and `LastChangedDate LastChangedRevision` as property value.

And when I commit from `NetBeans` it looks like this:

```
/*
 * $LastChangedDate: 2012-02-13 17:38:57 +0200 (Пн, 13 II 2012) $
 * $LastChangedRevision: 27 $
 */
```

Thanks all for the support! I will accept my answer because other answers do not include the `NetBeans` information. Nevertheless I give `+1` to the other answers.

Comment: This can be done in Eclipse as well: Right click on the project tree. select **Team -> Set Property**, choose `svn:keywords` from **Property name** list and type into **Enter a property** text box: `LastChangedDate LastChangedRevision`

Comment: When trying to add svn:keywords, nothing happens in NB 8.

Answer (score 12):

As this data only exists *after* the file was committed it should be set by SVN itself, not a client program. (And client-side processing tends to get disabled or not configured at all.) This means there is no simple template/substitute like you want, because then after the first replacement the template variables would be lost.

You can find information abut SVN's keyword substitution [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html). Then things like `$Rev$` can be replaced by `$Rev: 12 $`.

Answer (score 5):

I followed Petar Minchev's suggestions, only I put the $LastChangedRevision$ tag not in a comment block but embedded it in a string. Now it is available to programmatically display the revision number in a Help -> About dialog.

```
String build = "$LastChangedRevision$";
```

I can later display the revision value in the about dialog using a String that has all of the fluff trimmed off.

```
String version = build.replace("$LastChangedRevision:", "").replace("$", "").trim();
```

Comment: I use it the same way.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [The SubWCRev Program](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html).

> SubWCRev is Windows console program which can be used to read the
>   status of a Subversion working copy and optionally perform keyword
>   substitution in a template file. This is often used as part of the
>   build process as a means of incorporating working copy information
>   into the object you are building. Typically it might be used to
>   include the revision number in an “About” box.

This is typically done during the build process.

If you use Linux, you can find a Linux binary [here](http://www.compuphase.com/svnrev.htm). If you wish, you could also write your own using the output of `svn log`.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend a slightly different approach.

Put the following header at the top of your source files.

```
/*
 * This file was last modified by {username} at {date} and has revision number {revisionnumber}
 */
```

Then add a shell script like this

post update, checkout script

```
USERNAME=# // use svnversion to get username
DATE=# // use svnversion to get revisio nnumber
sed -e "s#{username}#${USERNAME}#" -e "s#{date}#${DATE}#" ${SOURCE_CONTROL_FILE} > ${SOURCE_FILE}
```

pre commit script

```
cat standard_header.txt > ${SOURCE_CONTROL_FILE}
tail --lines $((${LENGTH}-4)) ${SOURCE_FILE} >> ${SOURCE_CONTROL_FILE}
```