# Netbeans SVN commit with keywords in header

Tags: java, linux, svn, netbeans

I have defined a header to appear at the top of all my Java source files with some SVN keywords to be substituted by SVN. eg.

```
/*
* $LastChangedDate$
* $LastChangedRevision$
* $LastChangedBy$
*/
```

When I commit to my SVN repository I want SVN to substitute the correct values but this isn't happening. I've read that if I change my SVN config file to have the following:

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
*.java = svn:keywords=LastChangedDate LastChangedRevision LastChangedBy;
```

Then it should work, alas it has not. I have tried to change the two versions of the config file I have found

```
~/.subversion/config
~/.netbeans/8.0.2/config/svn/config/config
```

But still no joy. Any ideas?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9263373/823393) seems to work for me. I had no idea you could do that so thanks.

Comment: Awesome thanks, when you save a SVN property in netbeans where does it save it to? I'd like to export this setting so others can import it as part of their project