# SVN keywords config

Tags: java, linux, svn, version-control

Following my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101396/netbeans-svn-commit-with-keywords-in-header) I'd like to auto substitute SVN keywords when I commit from the command line. Eg

```
/**
* $LastChangedDate$
*/
```

Will become

```
/**
* $LastChangedDate: 2006-07-22 21:42:37 -0700 (Sat, 22 Jul 2006) $
*/
```

I have my ~/.subversion/config file as follows (note the miscellany section enable-auto-props = yes and the auto-props section *.java value)

```
### This file configures various client-side behaviors.
###
### The commented-out examples below are intended to demonstrate
### how to use this file.

### Section for authentication and authorization customizations.
[auth]
### Set password stores used by Subversion. They should be
### delimited by spaces or commas. The order of values determines
### the order in which password stores are used.
### Valid password stores:
###   gnome-keyring        (Unix-like systems)
###   kwallet              (Unix-like systems)
###   keychain             (Mac OS X)
###   windows-cryptoapi    (Windows)
# password-stores = keychain
# password-stores = windows-cryptoapi
#else
# password-stores = gnome-keyring,kwallet
###
### Set KWallet wallet used by Subversion. If empty or unset,
### then the default network wallet will be used.
# kwallet-wallet =
###
### Include PID (Process ID) in Subversion application name when
### using KWallet. It defaults to 'no'.
# kwallet-svn-application-name-with-pid = yes
###
### The rest of this section in this file has been deprecated.
### Both 'store-passwords' and 'store-auth-creds' can now be
### specified in the 'servers' file in your config directory.
### Anything specified in this section is overridden by settings
### specified in the 'servers' file.
###
### Set store-passwords to 'no' to avoid storing passwords in the
### auth/ area of your config directory.  It defaults to 'yes',
### but Subversion will never save your password to disk in
### plaintext unless you tell it to (see the 'servers' file).
### Note that this option only prevents saving of *new* passwords;
### it doesn't invalidate existing passwords.  (To do that, remove
### the cache files by hand as described in the Subversion book.)
# store-passwords = no
### Set store-auth-creds to 'no' to avoid storing any subversion
### credentials in the auth/ area of your config directory.
### It defaults to 'yes'.  Note that this option only prevents
### saving of *new* credentials;  it doesn't invalidate existing
### caches.  (To do that, remove the cache files by hand.)
# store-auth-creds = no

### Section for configuring external helper applications.
[helpers]
### Set editor-cmd to the command used to invoke your text editor.
###   This will override the environment variables that Subversion
###   examines by default to find this information ($EDITOR, 
###   et al).
# editor-cmd = editor (vi, emacs, notepad, etc.)
### Set diff-cmd to the absolute path of your 'diff' program.
###   This will override the compile-time default, which is to use
###   Subversion's internal diff implementation.
# diff-cmd = diff_program (diff, gdiff, etc.)
### Set diff3-cmd to the absolute path of your 'diff3' program.
###   This will override the compile-time default, which is to use
###   Subversion's internal diff3 implementation.
# diff3-cmd = diff3_program (diff3, gdiff3, etc.)
### Set diff3-has-program-arg to 'yes' if your 'diff3' program
###   accepts the '--diff-program' option.
# diff3-has-program-arg = [yes | no]
### Set merge-tool-cmd to the command used to invoke your external
### merging tool of choice. Subversion will pass 4 arguments to
### the specified command: base theirs mine merged
# merge-tool-cmd = merge_command

### Section for configuring tunnel agents.
[tunnels]
### Configure svn protocol tunnel schemes here.  By default, only
### the 'ssh' scheme is defined.  You can define other schemes to
### be used with 'svn+scheme://hostname/path' URLs.  A scheme
### definition is simply a command, optionally prefixed by an
### environment variable name which can override the command if it
### is defined.  The command (or environment variable) may contain
### arguments, using standard shell quoting for arguments with
### spaces.  The command will be invoked as:
###   <command> <hostname> svnserve -t
### (If the URL includes a username, then the hostname will be
### passed to the tunnel agent as <user>@<hostname>.)  If the
### built-in ssh scheme were not predefined, it could be defined
### as:
# ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q
### If you wanted to define a new 'rsh' scheme, to be used with
### 'svn+rsh:' URLs, you could do so as follows:
# rsh = rsh
### Or, if you wanted to specify a full path and arguments:
# rsh = /path/to/rsh -l myusername
### On Windows, if you are specifying a full path to a command,
### use a forward slash (/) or a paired backslash (\\\\) as the
### path separator.  A single backslash will be treated as an
### escape for the following character.

### Section for configuring miscelleneous Subversion options.
[miscellany]
### Set global-ignores to a set of whitespace-delimited globs
### which Subversion will ignore in its 'status' output, and
### while importing or adding files and directories.
### '*' matches leading dots, e.g. '*.rej' matches '.foo.rej'.
# global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo
#   *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store
### Set log-encoding to the default encoding for log messages
# log-encoding = latin1
### Set use-commit-times to make checkout/update/switch/revert
### put last-committed timestamps on every file touched.
# use-commit-times = yes
### Set no-unlock to prevent 'svn commit' from automatically
### releasing locks on files.
# no-unlock = yes
### Set mime-types-file to a MIME type registry file, used to
### provide hints to Subversion's MIME type auto-detection
### algorithm.
# mime-types-file = /path/to/mime.types
### Set preserved-conflict-file-exts to a whitespace-delimited
### list of patterns matching file extensions which should be
### preserved in generated conflict file names.  By default,
### conflict files use custom extensions.
# preserved-conflict-file-exts = doc ppt xls od?
### Set enable-auto-props to 'yes' to enable automatic properties
### for 'svn add' and 'svn import', it defaults to 'no'.
### Automatic properties are defined in the section 'auto-props'.
enable-auto-props = yes
### Set interactive-conflicts to 'no' to disable interactive
### conflict resolution prompting.  It defaults to 'yes'.
# interactive-conflicts = no

### Section for configuring automatic properties.
[auto-props]
### The format of the entries is:
###   file-name-pattern = propname[=value][;propname[=value]...]
### The file-name-pattern can contain wildcards (such as '*' and
### '?').  All entries which match (case-insensitively) will be
### applied to the file.  Note that auto-props functionality
### must be enabled, which is typically done by setting the
### 'enable-auto-props' option.
# *.c = svn:eol-style=native
# *.cpp = svn:eol-style=native
# *.h = svn:keywords=Author Date Id Rev URL;svn:eol-style=native
# *.dsp = svn:eol-style=CRLF
# *.dsw = svn:eol-style=CRLF
# *.sh = svn:eol-style=native;svn:executable
# *.txt = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id Rev URL;
# *.png = svn:mime-type=image/png
# *.jpg = svn:mime-type=image/jpeg
*.java = svn:keywords=LastChangedDate LastChangedRevision LastChangedBy HeadURL
# Makefile = svn:eol-style=native
```

However if I make a change to a Java source file and then do a `svn commit` `$LastChangedDate$` isn't substituted. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto :

> The `svn:auto-props` property works like the runtime configuration to automatically set properties on files when they are **added or imported**.

You can check what auto-props apply to a file or dir before addition to a repo like so:

```
svn propget svn:auto-props -v --show-inherited-props <yourfile>
```

And to check props in effect after addition:

```
svn proplist -v <yourfile>
```