# Get current revision number of SVN working copy in java program

Tags: java, svn, logging

I'm trying to get the current revision number of the working copy to log it into the log file.

The software is written in Java. So how is it possible to access the revision number through Java?

Comment: you can use the svnkit api to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262959/include-svn-revision-number-in-source-code

Comment: @LucianNut thanks for the answer, but I don't want the revision number in the file I commit. I want it in the log file I generate with the program from SVN

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what kind of software you're writing - a webapp in a war? A standalone java program/client packaged in a jar? If you're creating a war or jar file, you can have your build put the SVN info into the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and your code can read it from there.

Comment: I create a jar file, but there are also some other files the jar is depending on like a config file. So I don't want to get the revision number when the jar was build. I want to get the current revision when I start the jar.

Comment: Your build process can put the current revision version into META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in your jar (I've done this many times with ant/maven) then your code can read it from there.

Answer (score -1):

use svnkit and use the folloing method:

```
SVNWCClient.doInfo()
```