# How to get next Revision number in SVN

Tags: android, eclipse, svn

I'm developing android application using eclipse and svn for version control.

I wanted to know the next Revision number of svn before committing my project source.

Form `Properties->Team->Show History`, i can get the current Revision number, but i cant assume that the next revision number will be always +1 , because from the branch if any commit made then the next Revision number would be +2 or +3 depends upon number of Commit from branch .

So please someone tell me how to get the next Revision number.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like something that may have an established solution already. What are you trying to do? If you are trying to put the revision number in your source, there are different approaches for that

Comment: s, i'm trying to set the Next Revision number as my version code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wanted to know the next Revision number of svn before committing my project source.

I don't think that's possible, for the exact reason you state: there could be revisions between when you receive the number, and when you commit. As far as I know, Subversion does not allow "locking" revision numbers - nor would it make sense.

> i'm trying to set the Next Revision number as my version code

There is an established workflow for inserting the revision number into your code base. That is probably what you want. It is explained in [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008843/subversion-add-revision-data-to-code-file-on-commit)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set the *next* revision number. It does not matter, if you use current revision + 1, or current revision + 42, or current revision - 123, as long as you use the same constant all the time (so the version code *increments* when the revision *increments*).

Given the possible choice of *all* constants as explained above, current revision + 0 is the most simple to chose and implement, as most version control systems can embed that number directly in the files.