# How to make TortoiseSVN to create a log file with the current rev number after commiting any files?

Tags: java, svn, tortoisesvn

I need to use the current SVN revision in my Java code.
I use TortoiseSVN, Eclipse, Java 1.8, Windows 7.

I tried 2 things:

1) buildnumber-maven-plugin:

Our connection to the SVN server is way too complicated to connect them via the IDE/Maven because of the company security rules.

2) svn:keywords:

I created a file (revTemp.txt) and inserted an svn keyword in it: $revision$. The svn keywords used as $revision$ works perfectly, and I can read the file with Java. The content of this file is always updated when I commit it.

My problem is that i have to commit the revTemp all the time when I commit other files to the repository.

Can you help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: if that file is changed it will automatically be staged for commit.

Comment: After I commit it the first time it wont be on the commit list anymore.

Comment: FYI, [another SO thread on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2008843/463206)